# Why FF 51.0.1 blocks page certificate?

Tags: firefox, ssl

**URL** https://nbteam.ru/

**SSL** - StartSSL (Free certificate). Identity Card Validation: class1-Yes, class2- no. Domain Validations: nbteam.ru - Yes. SSL/TLS Server: nbteam.ru - yes.

IE, Chrome, Safari, FF v51.0 - Ok.

FF v51.0.1 - SEC_ERROR_REVOKED_CERTIFICATE

Firefox no longer supports StartSSL certificates? Or the problem lies elsewhere?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Firefox no longer supports StartSSL certificates?

Exactly. Since StartSSL tried to cheat they were distrusted by at least Firefox and Chrome. From [Distrusting New WoSign and StartCom Certificates](https://blog.mozilla.org/security/2016/10/24/distrusting-new-wosign-and-startcom-certificates/):

> Distrust certificates with a notBefore date after October 21, 2016 which chain up to the following affected roots. ...

The certificate of the site in question has a notBefore date of 2016/12/09 which is after the deadline.

Answer (score 1):

I've created (renewed) my certs at startssl, and both chrome and firefox said it's secure. I think they have a new CA.